# Spring CSRF protection is not working with a PreAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have the following setup:

- Android app and web application using a shared REST API
- Authentication happens using a tokens
- Token is generated using a specific REST service
- A Pre authentication filter fetches the token from the request and authenticates the user (augments the SecurityContext)

I'm using Spring Security 4.0 with CSRF enabled.

The following scenario succeeds:

- The Android app authenticates using a call to /rest/login

  - This request has a permitAll and is ignored using a request matcher in the CsrfFilter
- The Android app calls /rest/some/secured/api

  - This request has a hasRole('..') protection and requires a valid CSRF token

The following scenario fails:

- The Android app restarts and checks if his token is still valid by calling /rest/token

  - This request has a permitAll protection and is ignored using the same request matcher
  - The Pre authentication filter has augmented the SecurityContext so the Spring RestController is able to check the Principal in the handler
- Any following request to secured APIs fail because of an invalid CSRF token.

I see that the CsrfAuthenticationStrategy removes the CSRF token in the failing scenario after the call to /rest/token.

Does any one have any idea why the second scenario fails?

I have checked https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2722, but my pre authentication filter sits already before the CSRF filter.

Many thanks!

Comment: How does it fail? What is the error message?

Comment: @RobWinch `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter: Invalid CSRF token found for http://***/rest/some/secured/api`

Comment: I also use my own filter after the CsrfFilter to put the CSRF token in a XSRF-TOKEN cookie so I can use AngularJS's support out of the box.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the flow, but based on the error it seems you may have logged out, logged in, or the session was timed out. If that is the case, you will need to get a new CSRF token.

Comment: A new session is indeed being created because when the app restarts, there is no JSESSIONID cookie. But even when we persist cookies and reuse them when the app restarts, thereby reusing the same http session, the same error occurs.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why the `CsrfAuthenticationStrategy` removes the token in the session in my situation. I provide the `Authentication` object to the security context _before_ Spring's `CsrfFilter` is invoked...